# Firebase ecommerce

Tags: android, firebase, e-commerce, firebase-analytics

I have some doubts about firebase ecommerce.

1. I [Firebase Documentation Ecommerce purchase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html#ECOMMERCE_PURCHASE) I don't have the parameters item ID or item value, how can I know which product the user bought
2. I put this, but I don't see transactions in the firebase

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.TRANSACTION_ID, "T04");
bundle.putDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, 2);
analytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.ECOMMERCE_PURCHASE, bundle);
```

Any help?

Comment: The docs you linked contain this:  _Note: If you supply the VALUE parameter, you must also supply the CURRENCY parameter so that revenue metrics can be computed accurately_

Answer (score 1):

To log enhanced ecommerce purchases event in Firebase so that you would be able to log various other parameters like item ID item value etc, you can use either of the two techniques.

1) Create ArrayList of Bundle and add Bundle products. Do the same for data. Put both bundles from Products and data into a new Bundle using *putParcelableArrayList* log that event using *logEvent* method call.

2) Make use of the Google Tag manager. Detailed description on [Enhanced ecommerce](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/enhanced-ecommerce). This method would also let you send Analytics custom parameters beyond the [limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param) of 100 characters.